# Play next song automatically in Iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-4

I got the background Process successfully. But the problem was when AVAudio player get finished it won't play automatically next song. But In Simulator it will work fine. In device only the Problem. Any one worked Out???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we want to activate the Remote Control system,then only the song list will play automatically.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

use this line in viewdidload method....

I did't test in window based application!!! Just try and reply me!!!

Comment: @Suresh -->if i have my music player added to window,where to put the above code..